# After having downloaded a big files from HTTP how to check if it's ok?

Tags: php, http, request, md5, checksum

Are there any way to send an http request to know for example the md5 of a file?

I need it because I have a php script that downloads a remote file from http and then writes it locally.

I would like to check if it was transfered right.

Thanks

Comment: There's a [`Content-MD5`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1864.html) header supposed to be in HTTP responses, but few webservers send it. For Apache it depends on the `ContentDigest On` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP (in reality TCP) has internal error checking, so everything you download ist correct. The only problem you can have is an incomplete download, so check for filesize.

Answer (score -1):

Without checksum at original server, either external or inside file (like .exe), you can't.
HTTP provides no such functionality.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't efficient, but you could download it twice and checksum each (with md5 or sha). If the two match, *and* the size matches the content-length header, it's probably correct.

Comment: or you have two copies of a corrupt file

Comment: yes, but then it's probably corrupt on the server as well, if both checksums match. it was still *transferred* "right".